# How to fill a multiple string to filter a data in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm going to build web to be used in search for label information
My database is in Google Sheets, so I went looking for a Google Sheets fetch and gave it a try. I have no experience with Google App Scripts so I want to fill all and search data form database but it can run just one of them how to do it all (first is .gs second is Index.html) this is my reference.

1. https://gist.github.com/neno-tech/15d9c3fe32a2d8896c1875b7a827a6e5
2. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EhzxSy-L5kBt5E-BA1B446G0OjQAuKqEgLUPpiZh3Pw/edit

This is my database : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-r4gD1zV3e0yrNJTnHezXRlv1w-aOf6UqQs_P2jsRY/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
  .setTitle('System Search Lable')
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, inital-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
 
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var concat = formObject.searchtext+formObject.searchtext2+formObject.searchtext3+formObject.searchtext4+formObject.searchtext5; 
  var result = "";
  if(concat){
      result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}

function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1j-r4gD1zV3e0yrNJTnHezXRlv1w-aOf6UqQs_P2jsRY'; 
  var dataRange        = 'Master Barcode!A2:O10';  
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var ar = [];
data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext.toString().toLowerCase())) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                  <center><form id="search-form" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search a Label</label>
                    </div><p>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Category">
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext2" name="searchtext2" placeholder="Size">
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext3" name="searchtext3" placeholder="Brand">
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext4" name="searchtext4" placeholder="Color">
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext5" name="searchtext5" placeholder="Lenght">
                      <br>
                    </div><p>
                    <button id="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-2">Search</button>
                    <span id="spinner" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </form>
                  </center>
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = "Loading";
            document.getElementById('spinner').classList.remove("d-none");
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = "Search";
            document.getElementById('spinner').classList.add("d-none");
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+ 
                              "<th scope='col'>Barcode</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Brand</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Standard</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Year</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Table</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Type</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Category</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Coil</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>X</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Size</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Lenght</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Weight</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Color</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Voltage</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Size lable</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The results are here is that I fill in only one field. What I mean is I filled out the required information into each field, however I would like to know a way to fill in all fields in order to make it easier to filter.

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your `search mutiple`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike https://imgur.com/a/stFej8L <<< I want to fill this all to filter a lable so that are easier to find but my code is just still run one by one. 
I must apologize for giving the title too. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand `search mutiple` from your reply. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by `I want to fill all and search data form database but it can run just one of them how to do it all`? I understand you want to filter the spreadsheet data according to the data coming from the HTML form, but I'm not sure I understand the exact outcome you are after. Also, can you provide a screenshot of your spreadsheet, so that the data structure is clarified?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Sz8x6VT <<< The results are here is that I fill in only 1 field. What I mean is I filled out the required information into each field. However, I would like to know a way to fill in all fields in order to make it easier to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter results based on the values you enter in the web form, pass all search elements to your `search` function and then check that that they are all either blank or match. This assumes that the search terms and the columns in your sheet are in the same order. Example:

```
const MAPPING = [7, 10, 2, 13, 11];

function processForm({ searchtext, searchtext2, searchtext3, searchtext4, searchtext5 }){ 
  let searchTerms = [searchtext, searchtext2, searchtext3, searchtext4, searchtext5];
  var result = "";
  if(searchTerms.find(Boolean)){
      result = search(searchTerms);
  }
  return result;
}

function search(searchTerms){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1B0hcELJcoLxiYXNCDx9iRl8JxijwgdFBkte90oPfCnY'; 
  var dataRange        = 'Master Barcode!A46:O1346';  
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var ar = [];
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (searchTerms.every((e, i) => !e || e === f[MAPPING[i]-1])) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: I tried adjusting as you suggested but still facing the same problem. But I doubt I don't understand this enough. Can you give more advice? that there should be more adjustments to be made.

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous answer wasn't very complete. I edited it again. Does it help now?

Comment: thanks for the answer. But now the program can't find any information.

Comment: Can you double check the spreadsheet ID and the data range? Also, can you add a screenshot of your database spreadsheet, as another commenter suggested?

Comment: I just changed the ID sheet and range while ago. As for the web database, I have edited the post.

Comment: I updated the code again to include a mapping from your form fields to your spreadsheet columns. Can you check again?

Comment: Hmm, I've tried adjusting it and I still can't find information.

Comment: There was a small off-by-one mistake. I edited it again. I also created a demo here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDZJ2NgEhJr2LfrSAWMcInDrE0v3nUmA21ie8AVarGM/edit#gid=0